# Degree of map from a curve of genus $0$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

The context is that I'm trying to understand the implication that if $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $0$ then $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$.

Using Riemann-Roch one can see that there exists a non-constant function $f \in k(C)$ (the function field of $C$) with exactly one simple pole at $P \in C$ and no poles anywhere else. If we can show $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ we need to show that $f$ induces a map of degree $1$ then we are done.

In for example Hartshorne II 6.10.1 this is done by saying that if $\varphi: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is the by $f$ induced morphism then $\varphi^*(0) = P$ and thus by II 6.9. $\deg \varphi  = \deg \varphi \deg (0) = \deg \varphi^*(0) = \deg P = 1$.

> I don't understand why $\varphi^*(0) = P$?

I have also seen that the degree of $\varphi$ is the degree of the divisors of poles of $f$. This I also have trouble seeing.

My thought process thus far is that we by definition (Hartshorne page 137) we have $$\varphi^* (0) = \sum_{Q \in \varphi^{-1}(0)} = v_Q(t) \cdot (Q)$$
where in this case since $\varphi$ is injective so $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ consists of a single point $Q$. Thus $\deg \varphi^*(0) = \deg v_Q(t) (Q) = v_Q(t)$ but I have no idea how to evaluate $v_Q(t)$. I know it can be seen as the ramification index but this does not seem to be necessary.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi, you are right computing $\varphi^*(0)$, but it is important to take in count that $v_Q(t)$ is equal to the -order of $Q$ as a zero or pole, and $P$ is a simple pole, so $\varphi^*(0)=1.P$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do we know that $v_Q(t)$ is equal to the -order of Q as a pole or a zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is answered in detail in these [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-782-introduction-to-arithmetic-geometry-fall-2013/9d3d75948f44aaa1b2258e948f7433c8_MIT18_782F13_lec19.pdf), Corollary 19.23.

Comment: It's best not to use link-only answers on MSE - links can change or die in the future. It would be better to include a summary of the argument here.